# PowerShell Socket-Server connected IP-Addresses

Tags: sockets, powershell

I started a socket-server by

```
    $endpoint = new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([system.net.ipaddress]::any, $port)
    $listener = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
```

Any client with any IP-Address (subject to change) is able to connect.
How do get the IP-Addresse of a connected client after it has connected and was accepted:

```
    if ( $listener.Pending()) {
        $client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient() 
        $stream = $client.GetStream();
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $stream
        $writer.AutoFlush = $true
        ...
    }
```

Unfortunately $client.IPAddress() (error) or $client.IPAddress (nothing) do not exists
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it through `$client.Client.RemoteEndPoint`